How can I use python regex to find as many matches as possible, leaving out those that are concatenations?
I have this string
"~/goofy.git$ /home/maria/L1-07-51.mdl /home/maria/L1-08-09.res"
I want to find every occurrence of a string that starts /home and ends in either res or mdl. And:

I want to /home/maria/L1-07-51.mdl and /home/maria/L1-08-09.res to be found separately
I do not want to find /home/maria/L1-07-51.mdl /home/maria/L1-08-09.res

I tried
>>> re.findall("/home.+(mdl|res)", "~/goofy.git$ /home/maria/L1-07-51.mdl /home/maria/L1-08-09.res")
['res']


re.findall("/home.*?(?:mdl|res)", text)

Why are the question marks and colons required? If you put it in a reply, I will accept it as the answer.

.+ is greedy, .*? is lazy. (?:mdl|res) is just a non-capturing group, you can still use a capturing one as in your regex, you will just need to use re.finditer then.

How could one understand that findall and finditer differ in this way?

It is a very well-known issue.
